# How to use a Macro to set cell formulas to use a custom function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, custom-function, google-sheets-macros

For my work, I automate procedures to assist my team members and staff.  With the help of a co-worker, we created a Google Sheets function that calculates the attendance points of all agents to display them in an array on a sheet.  Due to the size of the calculation, the function tends to crash frequently.  This is fixed by simply re-pasting the formula into the cell that it was in.

Google recently released Macros for Google Sheets and I have attempted to use the macros for this purpose; yet, since the function is in a container-bound script, the macro yields a "Reference error" when attempting to reset the function on the sheet.  I attempted to create a function to do this as well and received the same result.

The function that I attempted to use in order to reset the sheet's cells:

```
function ResetPoints(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('').setFormulaR1C1(
    '=calculateAttendancePoints(ARRAYFORMULA(Overview5.0!R11C1:R30C1))'
  );
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(20, 0).activate();

  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('').setFormulaR1C1(
    '=calculateAttendancePoints(ARRAYFORMULA(Overview5.0!R31C1:R50C1))'
  );
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(20, 0).activate();

  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('').setFormulaR1C1(
      '=calculateAttendancePoints(ARRAYFORMULA(Overview5.0!R51C1:R70C1))'
  );
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(20, 0).activate();

  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('').setFormulaR1C1(
      '=calculateAttendancePoints(ARRAYFORMULA(Overview5.0!R71C1:R91C1))'
  );
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(21, 0).activate();

  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('').setFormulaR1C1(
      '=calculateAttendancePoints(ARRAYFORMULA(Overview5.0!R92C1:R100C1))'
  );
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
}
```

I simplified the macro with only one cell. The formula updates to "**=calculateAttendancePoints(ARRAYFORMULA(#REF!))**" The error message is "unknown function: calculateAttendancePoints

```
function ResetPoints() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate(); 
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('') 
     .setFormula('=calculateAttendancePoints(ARRAYFORMULA(Overview5.0!$A$11:$A$30))');
}
```

And here is the manifest file:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": { },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "sheets": {"macros": [
    {
      "menuName": "calculateAttendancePoints",
      "functionName": "calculateAttendancePoints"
    },
    {
      "menuName": "ResetPoints",
      "functionName": "ResetPoints",
      "defaultShortcut": "Ctrl+Alt+Shift+5"
    }
  ]}
}
```

Is there a way to reset the custom function in the cell using a macro indirectly or through a function?

Comment: It doesn't make sense `ARRAYFORMULA(Overview5.0!R11C1:R30C1)`. By the other hand calculateAttendancePoint could be the problem. What does this custom function does?

Comment: The macro has to be in a container-bound script, as do the custom function, so i'm not sure what you mean by `yet, since the function is in a container-bound script, the macro yields a "Reference error" when attempting to reset the function on the sheet.`

Comment: @Ruben, the custom function finds the user in the defined range, calculates the points they are at, and the arrayformula assists to display the data in a range.  For example,


        A2:B3
        john smith  2
        Jack Johnson  0

Comment: @tehhowch, when the macro runs, the formula is reentered on the sheet with '=(ARRAYFORMULA('REF')' and when hovered over the function, it displays the error "calculateAttendancePoints does not exist"

Comment: Well, is the definition of `function calculateAttendancePoints()` in the document's script file? if not, then it is correctly stating that the function is absent. Custom functions and macros must be in the document they are being used in

Comment: @tehhowch, the function calculateattendancepoints  is a created function in the same document.  But, regardless if I place the entire function in the macro script, it still won't call that function since it's not a function created by Google sheets.  Is there a workaround to add it as a Google sheets accepted function in my sheet?

Comment: @Josh can you edit your post to include your project's manifest file? Also, consider updating the code in your question to be a minimal script that reproduces your issue - which I understand to be that a macro bound to document A and a custom function bound to document A do not work together.

Comment: @Josh formatted code, especially as part of an MCVE, belongs in your question and not the comments

Comment: @tehhowch the comments have been deleted and the code has been added to the original question.  Do you know if this is something that is not supported by Google Sheets?

Comment: Is calculateAttendancePoints a macro or a custom function? Add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues:

1. A range reference that contains special characters - such as a space or a period - needs to be wrapped in single quotes:
   `=myCustomFn(Overview5.0!B1)` should be
   `=myCustomFn('Overview5.0'!B1)`
   This should resolve the `#REF!` error that appears.
2. Macros are not supposed to take arguments or return values. [Per Apps Script documentation for macros](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros#creating_macros_in_apps_script):

   > 2. Write the macro function. Macro functions should take no arguments and return no values.

Based on this, you need to remove the declaration of `calculateAttendancePoints` from the `sheets.macros` portion of the manifest file. If you've logically separated your Apps Script project into multiple `.gs` files (e.g. code.gs & macros.gs), it would make sense to also move the definition of `calculateAttendancePoints` from `macros.gs` to `code.gs`. Your `ResetPoints()` function is a valid macro, as it takes no arguments and returns no values.

So a working script project should be similar to this layout:

#### code.gs

```
function calculateAttendancePoints(range) {
  ...
  return someValue;
}
function someOtherFunction(someArg) {
  ...
}
```

#### macros.gs

```
function ResetPoints() {
  ...
}
```

#### manifest.json

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": { },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "sheets": {"macros": [
    {
      "menuName": "ResetPoints",
      "functionName": "ResetPoints",
      "defaultShortcut": "Ctrl+Alt+Shift+5"
    }
  ]}
}
```

Comment: After attempting the solution you suggested, an error is appearing as  "Missing ) after argument list. (line 5, file "macros")Dismiss"  This is the line that is providing the error:  `.setFormula('=calculateAttendancePoints(ARRAYFORMULA('Overview5.0')!$A$11:$A$30)');
  
};`

Comment: @Josh you have an extra `)` after `'Overview5.0'`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.  It appears that the setValue('') function that was being applied through the macro caused the function to determine an error.  The additional quotations cause an error in the script the disallow the function to run.

After correcting this piece on the script file, the function runs as intended. 
Thank you all for your help!